# Independent variables affected by size, how I resolve this problem?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, multicollinearity, nonlinear-regression

I am doing a research about the impact of trade unions on permanent contracts. The dependent variable is trade union presence (0,1), the independent variable is number of permanent contracts celebrated in a year, and there are many control variables such as firm size. But the larger the firm more contracts are celebrated, so, how can I correct this?

I'm thinking about a quantile regression based on size, or standardize the independent values based on size, or use log-transformation. Do you have any suggestion for me to do this regression?

Comment: Would dividing indep vars by the firm size help? So like a contracts/employees or something like that? I often do this in the context of econometric indicators, like GDP, which is larger based on population (GDP per cap).